# Set the width of ggplot geom_path based on a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two functions, `a` and `b`, that each take a value of `x` from 1-3 and produce an estimate and an error.

```
x    variable    estimate   error
1    a           8          4
1    b           10         2
2    a           9          3
2    b           10         1
3    a           8          5
3    b           11         3
```

I'd like to use geom_path() in ggplot to plot the estimates and errors for each function as x increases.

So if this is the data:

```
d = data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),variable=rep(c('a','b'),3),estimate=c(8,10,9,10,8,11),error=c(4,2,3,1,5,3))
```

Then the output that I'd like is something like the output of:

```
ggplot(d,aes(x,estimate,color=variable)) + geom_path()
```

but with the thickness of the line at each point equal to the size of the error. I might need to use something like `geom_polygon()`, but I haven't been able to find a good way to do this without calculating a series of coordinates manually.

If there's a better way to visualize this data (y value with confidence intervals at discrete x values), that would be great. I don't want to use a bar graph because I actually have more than two functions and it's hard to track the changing estimate/error of any specific function with a large group of bars at each x value.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to map `size` to `error` so that the size of the geometric object will vary depending on the value, `error` in this case. There are many ways to do what you want like you have suggested.

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                variable = rep(c('a','b'), 3), 
                estimate = c(8,10,9,10,8,11), 
                error = c(4,2,3,1,5,3))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, estimate, colour = variable, group = variable, size = error)) + 
  geom_point() + theme(legend.position = 'none') + geom_line(size = .5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `geom_ribbon()`. The answer is something like this:

```
ggplot(d,aes(x,estimate,ymin=estimate-error,ymax=estimate+error,fill=variable)) + geom_ribbon()
```